# how to change grub for doing the script

Tags: grub2, suse, clone

ater cloning my HDD on an OPEN SUSE 13.1 PC with Acronis True Image 2021 I followed the advices written on the Acronis pages. [ATI-CLONE_LINUX-INFO](https://kb.acronis.com/content/1686)
But when I start now I come in the GRUB2 CLI.
when I do

```
    set root=(hd0,1)
    configfile /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

I can boot.
What need I to do that this is done automatically at boottime?
SOrry to ask this simply question, but I am novice to GRUB and GRUB2.

Thanks
Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in GRUB CLI I did:

```
    set root=(hd0,1)
    linux /vmlinuz/<last-desktop-kernel> root=/dev/sda1 ro splash
```

To see which kernels are in the /vmlinuz diretory type `ls` or hit the `TAB`-Key to enter teh name automatically.

```
    initrd /<here again teh corresponging initrd.img>
    boot
```

Now I could boot into my SUSE 13.1 System, and then I did

1. editing the fstab file with the UUID of the HDDs, which should be mounted (see [How_to_get_UUIDs_of_your_HDDs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/))
2. started `Yast2` and there in
   `BootLoader` I put the Grub2 into the MBR.
   After that I could boot in the normal way.